# Security Issue - Harmful content

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot, malware

I am trying to solve an issue with my website already for some time but without any luck.

Google has detected somewhere in my website harmful content (Malware). But the problem is, I could not find anything harmful there.

Here is what I have checked:

- bad/wrong/not mine iframes (both - hidden and visible ones);
- bad/wrong/not mine script rows;
- SSL configuration for server;
- Server firewall;
- Other Malware and SSL scanning tools, like:

  https://www.scanmyserver.com/

  https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

  http://www.quttera.com/

  None of these scanning tools showed anything about harmful content.

I just can't find anything that would be harmful there.

Also, I checked the Google Search Console:

- In security issues, there were written two pages: http://produkt-guiden.dk/ and https://produkt-guiden.dk/PVMJ2
  After resubmitting the security check, I have now four pages: previous two + https://produkt-guiden.dk/ and https://produkt-guiden.dk/kabler/strom-kabler
- I tried to fetch and render the front page "/" but I did not see any differences that would point out some harmful content. Basically, both versions were quite similar.
- There is written this text in Search Console "Unfortunately, the malicious code within the page could not be isolated." which is very strange that they can detect something but can not tell me approximately what is wrong so that I could prevent that particular issue.

This website is running a Magento 1.9.1.0 version and it is an online shop.

The link to my website is this: https://produkt-guiden.dk/

I would appreciate any help from the community that could point out at least the direction where should I look for the issue before I can resubmit to check the security again.

So far, the website is marked insecure and visitors get this red screen with warnings and alerts.

Comment: Have you tried "fetch as google" (without rendering) and looking at the returned source code?  Sometimes malware inserts hidden content only for googlebot that will only show up in the source code send to Google.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, I have checked that as well. Also, I have quickly run through my php files to check for something harmful that pops into my eyes. It has been quite similar with the fetching as google - in 6000 lines it quite difficult to go through them all but in brief look I did not see anything suspicious :/

Comment: FWIW it also gives a security warning for visitors to the site.

Comment: Go to your files through FTP and search for those which has been edited in the last days/weeks. That usually is a good point to start finding the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen about a month ago on a site that has galleries of 32 pictures on every page. Google's Adwords bot decided that the thumbnail links to the full-sized pictures were a "link farm," which any human user could tell was absurd, but which apparently wasn't quite so obvious to a robot.

Adwords suspended the client's ads because the landing pages linked to what the robot had decided were link farms. Because he is a paying customer, however, the client was able to contact his rep at Google. After half a dozen phone calls to various agents over the course of a week, a human actually looked at the pages and decided that they weren't link farms after all.

The reason it took about half a dozen phone calls is because as best as I can tell, the first few Google reps to "review" the pages couldn't actually *see* the pages. They could only see the robot's report that said they were link farms. They kept telling me to remove the "links" -- and trying to explain to them that the links merely opened the full-sized pictures was pointless.

It was very frustrating because anyone who knew anything whatsoever about HTML could tell what the links were simply by looking at the code. The thumbnails and the full-sized pictures have the same filenames, and the thumbs are in directories named "thumbs" that open the full-sized pictures. I mean, how obvious does it have to be?

In any event, it took about three or four calls before the case was "escalated" to someone who actually looked at the pages in a Web browser, upon which it became obvious that the links were just gallery links. Even then, it took another day or two for the ban to be removed.

The other interesting thing is that only Adwords, not Google Search, had any problem with the pages. There was no "malicious content" warning, no problems noted on the Search Console, and SERP wasn't affected at all. It was only the Adwords bot, not the "regular" search bots, that decided the galleries were link farms. I guess some bots are dumber than others.

The moral of the story is that bots don't "see" pages the way humans do. Try to think like a robot. Your "malicious" pages may not be malicious at all.

Comment: I like it when people share personal stories. Cheers!!